# Typescript: What is this typing method for typing a function called?

Tags: typescript, function, types

Let's say I create a type like so:

```
type FunctionType = (param1: Param1Type, param2: Param2Type) => void;
```

I then want to use this to type a function:

```
<FunctionType>function(param1, param2) {
    // ...do stuff
  }
```

1. Is this bad practice? Should I type out all of my functions?
   The reason I am asking is I have a good number of functions that are all typed the same. So I was trying to find a better method instead of typing each param and return.
2. I like the arrow functions (as anyone should). Is there a way to convert this method of typing to an arrow function? (If this isn't good practice then I won't proceed)

TLDR: I saw this method used on a SO question elsewhere. Thought it looked neat but I don't know what it is called or how to use it with an arrow function

Comment: There's no strong need to make function types *unless* you plan to use them in higher order functions (you want to pass functions as arguments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The angle brackets are just a cast, this isn't special function syntax. There are slightly varying semantics vs annotations to be aware of though.
   For instance, if your function takes fewer arguments than `FunctionType`, it's a valid cast, but it's still a type error to call that function with the same number of args as `FunctionType` unless you assign the result of the cast to a variable. There may be other things that I'm missing as well.
   That being said, I don't think it's common, but probably not horrible practice.
2. You can annotate the variable if you are using an arrow function. This is probably the most idiomatic/common imo

```
const fn: FunctionType = () => {}
```

or cast it like you are the `function` syntax if you aren't assigning it to something

```
(<FunctionType> (param1, param2) => {})
```